# Having trouble setting document.getElementById and then sessionStorage.setItem

Tags: javascript, html, variables, session-storage

I am using HTML and JavaScript for a Wi-Fi landing page (called Splash.html). With Splash.html I need to get variable names with `document.getElementById` and then set name with `sessionStorage.setItem`. This information is then retrieved by another html page (called Test.html) but when I am redirected to Test.html it replies with "0". I am not an expert but that says to me that the variable names are not being stored properly. Could someone please look at my code and offer some help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0061da">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1643a3">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
  <title>
    SmartPlay TV
  </title>
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="wifi_landing.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    var rootPath = "/xxx/";
    var defaultImgPath = "/xxx/assets/front/assets/images/products/7.png"
    var firstPath = "http://xxx/xxx/";
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="login-form-bg-image-tablet">
    <img id="back" src="back_5dc4a0740c93eclouds-1586540_960_720.jpg" onerror="this.src = '/xxx/assets/img/tablet.jpg'"></div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="page-main">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 landing-left">
          <div class="row mark-img row-logo">
            <div class="col-md-12 mark-img-rect">
              <img id="logo" src="logo_5dc4a05f10a24201906271242crop479976885.jpg" onerror="this.src = '/xxx/assets/img/wifilanding-mark.png'"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mark-img row-url">
            <div class="col-md-12 mark-mark-rect text-center">
              <span id="url" style="word-break: break-word;">www.basicplasticsurgery.com</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 textarea-rect" style="display: flex;">
              <span id="box_title" class="text3 text" style="padding: 20px 30px; background: white; width: 100%; position: unset; word-break: break-word; border: 2px solid grey;"><p>Welcome to Basic Plastic Surgery!<br><br>Your decision to improve your appearance can be one of the most important investments you make for yourself&acirc;&#128;&#147;and your self-confidence. Our staff take every measure to ensure that you receive the highest quality care in a professional, comfortable environment.</p></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 landing-right">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="gallery">
              <div class="row media-rect">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 media-ele-wrapper">
                  <img src="upload1_5dbb7ff59f88074670796_10219304255335727_5029165459597950976_o.jpg" class="file-rect" id="upload1" onerror="noExitImg(this);">
                  <div class="textbox-rect text-overflow-ellipsis" style="min-height:80px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
                    <span class="title" id="upload1_desc">CoolSculpting.
    Please see front desk for more info</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 media-ele-wrapper">
                  <img src="upload2_5dc4a2905bfdb209508_4516468915805_534071624_o.jpg" class="file-rect" id="upload2" onerror="noExitImg(this);">
                  <div class="textbox-rect text-overflow-ellipsis" style="min-height:80px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
                    <span class="title" id="upload2_desc">Me playing soccer.</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 media-ele-wrapper">
                  <img src="upload3_5dc4a2976ac89IMG_5313.JPG" class="file-rect" id="upload3" onerror="noExitImg(this);">
                  <div class="textbox-rect text-overflow-ellipsis" style="min-height:80px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
                    <span class="title" id="upload3_desc">BPS Background</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 media-ele-wrapper">
                  <img src="upload4_5dcddf7d5131a20191017_220631.jpg" class="file-rect" id="upload4" onerror="noExitImg(this);">
                  <div class="textbox-rect text-overflow-ellipsis" style="min-height:80px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
                    <span class="title" id="upload4_desc">BPS

    Test</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 landing-sign-rect">
              <div class="landing-sign-rect-form">
                <div class="menu1">
                  <span id="box_text" style="word-break: break-word;">In order to access the internet we need some information. Please submit the following info to use our wifi network.


    If you don't submit information you cannot use our network.</span>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control autosize" onkeydown="resize(this)" onkeyup="resize(this)" rows="1" id="user_name" style="resize:none;" placeholder="First Name">Full Name</textarea></div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                  <textarea class="form-control autosize" onkeydown="resize(this)" onkeyup="resize(this)" rows="1" id="user_name1" style="resize:none;" placeholder="Last Name">Email</textarea></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control autosize" onkeydown="resize(this)" onkeyup="resize(this)" rows="1" id="user_email" style="resize:none;" placeholder="Email Address">Tell us what products you're interested in learning about:







    </textarea></div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                  <!-- <button class = "btn" type = "button" style = "background:#0073c3;color: white;">Sign In</button> -->
                  <!-- <form method="get" action="$authaction" onsubmit="SubmitFunc()"> -->
                  <form method="get" action="http://192.168.50.10:2050/nodogsplash_auth/" onsubmit="SubmitFunc()">
                    <input type="hidden" name="tok" value="$tok"><input type="hidden" name="redir" value="$redir"><input style="background:#0073c3;color: white;" type="submit" value="Sign In"></form>
                </div>
                <div class="menu3">
                  Powered by SmartPlay TV
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It continues with JavaScript section:

```html
<script>
  function SubmitFunc() {

    sessionStorage.clear();

    var name = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    var name1 = document.getElementById("user_name1").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("user_email").value;

    sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
    sessionStorage.setItem("name1", name1);
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);

  }

  function resize(obj) {
    obj.style.height = "1px";
    obj.style.height = (25 + obj.scrollHeight) + "px";
  }
</script>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom_new.js"></script>
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
  initResize();

  function alignTextBox() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 770) {
      jQuery(".media-rect").css("height", "");
      jQuery(".textarea-rect .text2").css("min-height", "");
      return;
    } else {
      jQuery(".textarea-rect .text2").css("min-height", "680px");
    }
  }

  function initResize() {
    var fileRectObj = jQuery(".file-rect").eq(0);
    var width = fileRectObj.width();
    var height = width * 9 / 16; // 16:9 to width
    jQuery(".file-rect").css("height", height + "px");
    alignTextBox();
  }
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    initResize();
  })
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.autosize').each(function() {
      resize(this);
    });
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the Test.html script that includes the `getItem` part:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h3 style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center;">Thank you for your submission. You can now browse the internet freely.</h3>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEmail1() {
      console.log('sending email');

      var name = localStorage.getItem("user_name");
      var name1 = localStorage.getItem("user_name1");
      var email = localStorage.getItem("user_email");

      alert(name + name1 + email);

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // xhr.open('GET', 'sendEmail.php?name=john&name1=name1&email=test');
      xhr.open('GET', 'http://192.168.50.10:8000/htdocs/sendEmail.php?name=' + name + '&name1=' + name1 + '&email=' + email);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {}
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

    function sendEmail2() {
      console.log('sending email');

      var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
      var name1 = localStorage.getItem("name1");
      var email = localStorage.getItem("email");

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // xhr.open('GET', 'sendEmail.php?name=john&name1=name1&email=test');
      xhr.open('GET', 'sendEmail.php?name=' + name + '&name1=' + name1 + '&email=' + email);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);

          // return false;
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    }


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
      // alert('ready');

      // alert(localStorage.getItem("email") + ":" + sessionStorage.getItem("email"));
      // alert(sessionStorage.getItem("email") + ":" + localStorage.getItem("email"));

      sendEmail1();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the bit you use to get variables from session storage? There must be a `getItem`?

Comment: I just edited the post with that code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Test.html is using `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, even after changing Test.html to use sessionStorage I get the following alert: "Page at http://192.168.50.10 says: 0" so the info is still not being passed along properly.